# How to get the same output order from a Java Collection

Tags: java, data-structures, graph, collections, jung

I have some code:

```
Collection<MyGraph.MyVertex> vertCollection = graph.getVertices();
```

where getVertices is part of the JUNG package and is defined like:

```
public interface Hypergraph<V, E> {
    Collection<E> getEdges();

    Collection<V> getVertices();
...
...
}

> If I print out the collection I may get something like [v1,v2,v4,v3]
> and on another run something like [v2,v3,v1,v4]
```

That gives me back a list of vertices in random order each time. Because of this my results elsewhere in the code are not repeatable and it gets hard to trace.

I want to get the elements back in order each time the same way. My current guess is I'd have to convert the collection to some sort of data structure that preserves order then sort it so that the results are repeatable but is there a better way to do this? (I'm not sure if converting from a Collection to something else like an array would break the code elsewhere as I'm  new to Collections). Any help would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood that `Hypergraph.getVertices()` is a library method that you cannot modify. So you have to manipulate the result from a call to that method. Sorting is the option here, as suggested by [Yamil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61644563/1554195).

But this requires that either your implementation of `<V>` (`MyGraph.MyVertex` in your sample) will implement `java.lang.Comparable`, or that you provide an implementation of `java.util.Comparator` that ensures a static sort order for your vertices.

And `java.util.Collections.sort()` takes a `List` as argument; an instance of `List` is always an instance of `Collection`, too, but unfortunately not every instance of `Collection` is an instance of `List` – it could be a `Set` or even something absolute strange …

Considering this, and assuming that `VertComparator` is the comparator I talked about, your solution might look like this:

```
…
VertComparator comparator = new VertComparator();
List<MyGraph.MyVertex> vertCollection = new ArrayList<>( graph.getVertices() );
Collections.sort( vertCollection, comparator );
…
```

If all other code in your program does only deal with `Collection` instances of vertices (that means that no hidden assumptions are made somewhere what kind of collection it is), you should be safe.

Unfortunately, even if the returned `Collection` is already an instance of `List` (`… instanceof List` yields true), `Collections.sort()` may not work: create your list with `List.of()` and try to sort it …

Quite often, when a method returns a `Collection` that somehow represents the internal status of the object, this is an unmodifiable collection. Obviously sorting will fail here, too. So the only safe way is to copy the result and sort the copy.

Comment: So there'd be no way of simply converting the Collections to a list and calling some already built in sort? I was able grab the int IDs from the vertices when looping through the ArrayList version of the Collections. I would have to implement my own comparator/comparable?

Comment: No, unfortunately not! And even if the collection is already a `List`, sort may not work. Create your list with `List.of()` and try to sort it … And when a method returns a `Collection` representing the internal status of the object, it is quite often an unmodifiable collection. Obviously sorting will fail here, too. So the only safe way is to copy the result and sort the copy.

Comment: And yes, if your vertex class does not implement `Comparable` already, you need an implementation of `Comparator` that uses the integer IDs for sorting. If that does not exist already, you have to implement it yourself; but with lambdas, that's a one-liner: `(v1,v2) -> Integer.signum( v1.getID() - v2.getID() )`, and it can used directly as the second argument to the call to `Collections.sort()`.

Comment: @tquadrat don’t use minus for a comparator when you don’t know the exact value space. The distance between two `int` values can be larger than fitting into the `int` value space, hence, may overflow. On the other hand, there is no need to call `signum` here. So a correct comparator would be `(v1,v2) -> Integer.compare(v1.getID(), v2.getID())` or `Comparator.comparingInt(v -> v.getID())`. Alternatively, `Comparator.comparingInt(MyGraph.MyVertex::getID)`. By the way, instead of `Collections.sort( vertCollection, comparator );` you can use `vertCollection.sort(comparator);`

Answer (score 1):

You could use something like this:

```
List<String> names = Arrays.asList("Alex", "Charles", "Brian", "David");

//Natural order
Collections.sort(names);    //[Alex, Brian, Charles, David]

//Reverse order
Collections.sort(names, Collections.reverseOrder());    [David, Charles, Brian, Alex]
```

Answer (score 1):

As you've seen, JUNG 2.x doesn't provide this option natively, so your only real option is to copy the output and sort it, and that assumes that you have a `Comparator` that makes sense for your vertex type.  (Nor does this make it easy to preserve the original insertion order.)

The [Guava graph library](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained), also known as `common.graph`, is used by [JUNG 3.0](https://github.com/jrtom/jung) (in development) and does support stable ordering, on a couple of different levels:

1. [`Immutable` graphs](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained#immutable-implementations)' accessors each return a `Set` with a stable ordering.
2. If you want a [mutable graph](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained#mutable-types), the built-in implementations, which are constructed using [`GraphBuilder`](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/GraphsExplained#building-graph-instances) (and its sibling types) can specify using [`nodeOrder()`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/graph/GraphBuilder.html#nodeOrder-com.google.common.graph.ElementOrder-) that the graph nodes should be any of the following:

   - insertion-ordered (default)
   - unordered
   - naturally ordered (if your node type implements `Comparable`)
   - sorted

   For `Networks` (which are analogous to the JUNG `Graph` type) you can impose the same ordering on the edges of the graph.
3. You can also construct a mutable graph which provides stable-ordering guarantees for some of the node-level accessors (`successors()`, `predecessors()`, etc.) using [`incidentEdgeOrder()`](https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/graph/GraphBuilder.html#incidentEdgeOrder-com.google.common.graph.ElementOrder-) on the graph `Builder`.

(Disclaimer: I co-created JUNG and still maintain it, and also created `common.graph`.)

Comment: Wow the man himself! Thanks for the library! My out of order problem was specifcally pertaining to when I printed out the source vertex in the singleSourceShortestPath() definition, it would print a different order of nodes every time I ran dijkstras. Is this expected behavior with JUNG? If so, is there a workaround to get a deterministic way of feeding in the nodes/running the algo? If it's not expected behavior, it may be because I'm working with a code base that has some custom implementations of DijkstraDistance/ShortestPath.

Comment: I was only trying to sort the Collection because I saw that the getVertices() call was giving things back out of order so I thought that might have had something to do with the out of order algorithm runs, but after sorting the collection it still prints sources out of order

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "printing out the source vertex in... singleSourceShortestPath()".  Are you saying that you're getting a different shortest path?  I think that this is a different question that should be asked separately, ideally with sample code.  :)

Comment: singleSourceShortestPath(source, targets, numDests) refers to the method in JUNG's DijkstraDistance class that "Implements Dijkstra's single-source shortest-path algorithm for weighted graphs.". When I run it, I print out source immediately and it turns out source is different each time. I don't think it's getting different paths, but starting the algorithm on a diff/random node each time. I'm looking into using DirectedOrderedSparseMultigraphs instead but yeah I think I may post a new question later on.

Comment: Because the first source is diff each time, the next source is diff as well and it ends up with an entirely different traversal order each time. I basically just want the algorithm to run in a repeatable manner where the order of traversal/source for each iteration is the same but I'm not sure if that;s possible with JUNG

Comment: I think I'm confused about what you're doing.  I know which method you're talking about.  "source" is something that you're specifying to that method, so I don't know what you mean by saying "the first source is different each time".  My best guess is that you're asking for the shortest path from each of a set of vertices, to each of a (possibly different) set of vertices.  The thing is: I'm not sure why you care what order the paths are reported in, so I assume I'm missing some context about the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an ArrayList to implement the Collection.  ArrayList's behave just like an array.  They come out in the same order they are put in.

```
Collection<E> list = new ArrayList<>();
Collection<V> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: As `Hypergraph.getVertices()` is – according to my understanding of the description – a library function that is just called by the TO, this is not an option at all.